# Downloading images list through python using a loop with user input

Tags: python, image, list, download

Downloading images list through python using a loop.
Hi guys,
I’m trying to create a python code that will do the following:
Download images URLS and theirs names from a user input
I couldn’t figure out how to loop through the names list.
Here user URLs input example:

https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png, https://www.fudzilla.com/media/k2/items/cache/3c6d36be2f570f2ea2f5d74c17c26ae0_XL.jpg

User Names input example:
Google,Apple

final result: having 2 images downloaded to 'images' folder with name file 'apple' and 'google'

Here’s the code i could come up with:

```
    import urllib.request

    images = input('please enter url list separated by ",""')
    names = input('please enter images names separated by ",""')

    images = images.split(',')
    names =  names.split(',')

    for image in images:
     for name in names:
              urllib.request.urlretrieve(image[0], "images/{}.jpg".format(name[0])) 
print('images downloaded successfully')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop seems wrong to me. By nesting two loops you will have 4 iterations in total, 2 for each loop. So you will make 4 requests. You are going to download each image two times and save it with both names. If I were you, I would use a dictionary with key:value pairs, but it's a completely different code. The following code will loop only through images and each time the name will be the incrementing index from the 'names' array.

Try this:

```
import urllib.request

images = input('please enter url list separated by ",""')
names = input('please enter images names separated by ",""')

images = images.split(',')
names =  names.split(',')

for index, image in enumerate(images):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image, "images/{}.jpg".format(name[index])) 
print('images downloaded successfully')
```

Comment: Thank you! Works Great!

Answer (score 0):

You're using nested loops, but I think you actually want just one loop that steps through the urls and names at the same time.

Try this:

```
images = input('please enter url list separated by ",""').split(',')
names = input('please enter images names separated by ",""').split(',')

for i in range(len(images)):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(images[i], "images/{}.jpg".format(names[i]))
```

Comment: Thank you! Works Great!